# Pycharm/VS Code for remote code editing with remote python interpreter (via SSH)?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, pycharm, remote-access

My Python code as well as my Python environment are on a remote server. I can access this server from my thin client via SSH. I'd like to use Pycharm or VS Code for remote editing. In order to use smart code navigation and autocompletion the IDE should also access the remote Python interpreter. I am aware of plugins for SSH remote editing but I haven't seen any integrations of remote interpreters. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm Professional has support for remote interpreters. The code base though needs to be local.

Comment: Thanks, it's true that this is supported by the pro version (not sure how I missed that). Is it possible to combine this with remote code editing or would one run into conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that now with the jetbrains gateway
https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/gateway/